# Discord.py (rewrite): Error Handling "Improper Token" In Function

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I feel like I'm missing a simple way to solve this problem, but I can't seem to find a way to handle the `discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.` error. What I'm trying to do is run a function that essentially runs a bot and repeats itself if it comes across any errors (with `try:` and `except:`) and if it catches the 'improper token' error then change a setting in my code and retry it.

What I believe is happening is that try/except isn't catching the error and it stops the program (printing the entire error in the process). I've tried some quick solutions like making the function into a while statement and until it reaches the end of the program it will keep repeating itself, however without catching the error I can't continue any code.

My code is messy and has to do with a lot of variables that are defines earlier in this large python file, so I won't show my entire function.

Here is the simplified version:

```py
def code(mainText):
    mainLines = mainText.split("\n")
    # Do some stuff editing mainText
    final = "\n".join(mainLines)
    try:
        exec(final, globals())
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        # edit 'final' a bit
        exec(final, globals())
```

The full error message:

```py
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<Client.start() done, defined at E:\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:526> exception=LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 258, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "E:\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 222, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 542, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "E:\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 400, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token, bot=bot)
  File "E:\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 262, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

As of writing this I found 'Task exception never retrieved' is this anything of importance or is that the usual 'improper token' error?

Thank you, sorry in advance for my bad coding practices and lack of experience using Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why are you using exec? Why not just write another function and send that function to be ran?

Comment: I have to use exec because 'final' is a string that pulls from multiple sources of input, I'd rather find a way to solve the problem while still using exec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I haven't tried it myself. This is my best answer as to what I can understand from your problem and error message:

```
#Put this at the bottom of your .py file
try:
    bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
except discord.errors.LoginFailure as e:
    print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the errors go past try/except even with excepting all exceptions.

Comment: @Miggy This worked for me. Also I edited my post to make sure it is what the same as what I just tried. You can also use bot.login(token, bot=True), but it must be in a function and and must be awaited.

Your error does mention improper token as been passed. Is is only raised when an invalid token was used in bot.run(token) or bot.login(token).

Comment: There must be something that is making my results different then yours. I tried try/except in the exec() where I ran the final script and the error shows up regardless.

Comment: @Miggy, post you're entire script on a notepad and upload it somewhere accessible, such as Google Drive or Microsoft OneDrive. I'll probably need to see the full script. You can remove any bot credentials you need.

Answer (score 1):

seen the fact there is a HTTPException and a Login Failure, you should have those both behind the except like this:

```py
try:
    bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
except discord.errors.HTTPException and discord.errors.LoginFailure as e:
    print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

this will catch the HTTPException as well. Becuse like I said, if you read the error you see there is a HTTPException **and** a LoginFailure. Both of those need to be catched if you want to catch the error and make a custom error message.

Answer (score -1):

Is your token a string?
Did you get it from the discord developer portal? i.e are you sure it's the right token?

Make sure BOT_TOKEN is a string and your token is valid

Comment: I don't think you understand the question I'm asking. What I am looking for is a way to catch any login failure errors, not fix them.